# How to create a windows batch file that sends a file to a bluetooth device?

Tags: batch-file, bluetooth

I'm always sending one file to a device.

The device is always the same and the file has the same path and name.

How do I write a batch file to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For Widcomm stack you shoud try

C:\Program Files\Widcomm\Bluetooth Software\btsendto_explorer.exe"   -BD_ADDR=

For Microsoft stack try this: http://www.newlc.com/topic-9327

Please excuse for this half answer, but I don't have my batch file for Widcomm at hand and I still recall how much trouble I went to 2 years ago trying to find the correct command line parameters.

You can contact me through my website if you succeed or if I should dig for the batch file :D

Best regards,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a Bluetooth enable phone then you could use CECopy from the Windows Mobile PowerToys.

See this link http://forums.thoughtsmedia.com/f96/copy-files-mobile-device-easily-14037.html for details of how to install / use it for creating new 'Send To' links - but the command lines should work as part of a batch script also ...

I'm not sure if it will work for other bluetooth devices ??

Comment: This is only for smartphones and pocket pcs, isn't it? I want to do this for a Nokia phone.

Comment: All Bluetooth devices use one of two standard ways to transfer files - either OBEX Push or OBEX FTP. Both work with all devices.